# How to set Telemetry Channel for Application Insights Log4Net Appender?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, log4net, azure-application-insights

I added those Nuget Packages to my WPF App:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel

The logger is logging in a file, that works. But no data is transferred to Azure. 
I got this error:

- AI: Server telemetry channel was not initialized. So persistent storage is turned off. You need to call ServerTelemetryChannel.Initialize(). Currently monitoring will continue but if telemetry cannot be sent it will be dropped.

My Question: Where (in the code) should i initialize the telemetry channel? And why do i have to do this? What's the appender for if i have to add a telemetry client (with config) anyways?

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 0603:**

my app.config:

[image]

Debug with visual studio:

### [image]

**Update:** please follow the screenshot below, and try to find the info you send. And if you still cannot find the info, please provide you detailed code(remove the personal/important data like instrumentation key, and also provide us the nuget package and version you're using).

1.click the search button in overview page:

[image]

2.in the search screen, make the Local time and Event types are set correctly, then try to search the message:

[image]

---

You'd better provide the code to set log4net and app insights key.

I did a simple test with wpf project, the below code works fine:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));
    public MainWindow()
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the key";
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log.Info("wpf aaaa11111");


        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

You get the error "AI: Server telemetry channel was not initialized", maybe due to some incorrect configuration, like use the following code in the above working code:

```
//when add the code, it will cause the error you mentioned.
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel();
```

If you have to add a telemetry client (with config), and with proper configuration, both log4net and telemetry client can send data to application insights. The code like below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //configure the key here for log4net
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the key";
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        var config = new TelemetryConfiguration();

        //configure the key here for telemetry client
        config.InstrumentationKey = "the key";
        telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);

        log.Info("wpf aaaa333");
        log.Info(TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.ToString());

        telemetryClient.TrackTrace("it is going to start!");

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: The telemetryClient.TrackTrace() is working, like still before. But I cannot find any data at Azure portal from the log.Info. 
Found out there's another major problem: I first have to figure out how and where to see logger.info, .error, .debug and so on at Azure portal. 
I will contact you again

Comment: I googled like the whole internet, but can't figure out how to see the log.Info (if it's successfully send) at azure portal. Please help!

Comment: @Houve, please see the updated section. If you still have problem, please provide more info as I mentioned in the updated section.

Comment: i created a new test wpf project and added exactly the first mentioned code above to the MainWindow.xaml.cs, but it still dont work. As NugetPackages I use log4net v2.0.8, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights v2.10.0 and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Lof4NetAppender v2.10.0

Comment: @Houve, can you show me the code of the test wpf project?

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));
    public MainWindow()
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the key";
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log.Info("wpf aaaa11111");


        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }

Comment: Well, I forgot 1 package: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel v2.10.0

Comment: I tried the second mentioned code and the telemetryClient.TrackTrace() works fine but log.Info() still don't work.
I also tried sending data via telemetryClient before like here: https://blog.e-zest.com/microsofts-azure-application-insights-for-wpf-desktop-application and this works.

It's just the log4nedAppender who sends nothing...

Comment: @Houve, just a quick test again, it did works at my side(the code log.info("xxxx")). 1. are you using visual studio? if yes, then during run the project, take a look at the output window, to see if there're the info sent by log.info("wpf aaa11111"), more details please refer to my updated section for the screenshot. 2. do you mind share me the app.config file?

Comment: @Houve, another possible reason is that, in the App.config file, you didn't set the log level to ALL or Info, so the log4net ignores the messages from log.Info("xxx"). I also updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally everything works. I offer the required steps here again:

1. Add NugetPackages: 
   log4net, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel to the Project
2. In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

   ```
   private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));
   public MainWindow()
   {
       TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the key";
       log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

       log.Info("wpf aaaa11111");


       InitializeComponent();
   }
   }
   ```
3. In App.config:
   [image: App.config]
4. Done

Big thanks to @Ivan Yang for his solution and his time helping me!